# Launch chrome with extension using protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm trying to launch chrome browser with "Modheader" extension using protractor by using the following in my conf.js

```
chromeOptions: {
  args: [
    '--load-extension=C:/Utilities/extension_2_2_4_0.crx'
  ],
```

But on running the test I get the following error:

```
Failed to load extension from ..... Manifest file is missing or unreadable
```

Is there any way to launch the browser with extension already installed  OR is there any way to provide header with URL using protractor

```
baseUrl= www.abc.com
Header= 'name' : 'testuser'
```